# How can I draw arrows between words in linguistic examples?

Tags: arrows, linguistics

This is what I'm after: I'd like to have the sentence 'John loves his mother.' displayed with an arrow running from 'his' to 'John'. I looked at `gb4e`, but I found the documentation confusing and I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: This one seems easier: http://www.let.uu.nl/~Alexis.Dimitriadis/personal/latex/underarrows.sty . In this case you would write: `\linkto John \under loves \from his mother`.

Comment: @Vivi: Why is this a comment and not an answer? =)

Answer (score 11):

Use TikZ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,text depth=0pt]
\tikz\node[na](word1){John}; loves \tikz\node[na](word2){his}; mother.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \path[->,red,thick](word2) edge [out=90, in=90] (word1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I don't know what type of arrow you want =)

Comment: The `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}` isn't needed.  Also, remember to compile it twice to get the arrows set correctly.