# Linguistics: What are the best packages to use create bracketed structures with movement lines?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

I've been working with gb4e to manage numbered examples for a long time, but I was wondering it was possible to incorporate movement lines, or if I should use some other package. More concretely, I would like to generate something like the below:

[image: Bracketed structures with movement]

Comment: Perhaps this answer: [Movement arrow in gloss](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140142/2693)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the best way to create the bracketed structures, but here I show how to insert the so-called movement lines: `\connect[direction]{left-end}{mid-text}{right-end}`.  Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\def\rlht{3ex}    \def\rlwd{.8pt} \def\rloffset{3pt}
\newcommand\vstrut[1][x]{%
  \def\stacktype{S}%
  \if x#1%
    \smash{\makebox[0pt]{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}}%
  \else%
    \smash{\makebox[0pt]{\stackon[-5pt]{\rule{\rlwd}{\rlht}}%
          {\hspace{.5\dimexpr\rlwd\relax}$\blacktriangle$}}}%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\conR[2][x]{%
  \savebox\tmpbox{#2}%
  \stackunder[\dimexpr\rlht-\rlwd\relax+\rloffset]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{%
    \rule{.5\wd\tmpbox}{0pt}\vstrut[#1]\rule{.5\wd\tmpbox}{\rlwd}}%
}
\newcommand\conL[2][x]{%
  \savebox\tmpbox{#2}%
  \stackunder[\dimexpr\rlht-\rlwd\relax+\rloffset]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{%
    \rule{.5\wd\tmpbox}{\rlwd}\vstrut[#1]\rule{.5\wd\tmpbox}{0pt}}%
}
\newcommand\conM[1]{%
  \savebox\tmpbox{#1}%
  \stackunder[\dimexpr\rlht-\rlwd\relax+\rloffset]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}{%
    \rule{\wd\tmpbox}{\rlwd}}%
}
\newcommand\connect[4][x]{%
  \if l#1\conR[a]{#2}\else\conR{#2}\fi%
  \conM{#3}%
  \if r#1\conL[a]{#4}\else\conL{#4}\fi\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand\lb[1]{[$_\mathrm{\scriptscriptstyle#1}\,$}

\begin{document}
\lb{TP}\itshape Seve%
\connect[l]{r}{al riots\upshape\lb{T}are]\lb{VP}\lb{V}believed]\lb{TP}%
  \lb{T}to]\lb{AUXP}\lb{AUX}have]\lb{VP}\lb{V}occurred]\lb{QP}}{t}%
\upshape]]]]]]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I once used `linguex` in conjunction with `pst-jtree`. That gives you all the power you need. Please excuse that I shortened the example somewhat. The `\jtree` command has to be called once in the document before the example for some reason. Also note that the document has to be compiled as `.ps` first.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}

\jtree
\endjtree
\exi. \rnode{a1}{X} [CP $\ldots$ [TP $\ldots$ \rnode{a2}{t} $\ldots$]]

\ncbar[angleA=270, angleB=270, linestyle=dashed]{<-}{a1}{a2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 0):

You know, actually there is an example of such a thing in the end of the `gb4e` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex\atcenter{\arrowalign{
\lb{TP} & \emph{Seveal riots} & \lb{T}are]\lb{VP}\lb{V}believed]\lb{TP}\lb{T}to]\lb{AUXP}\lb{AUX}have]\lb{VP}\lb{V}occurred]\lb{QP}&\emph{t}&]]]]]] \cr
&\fillright\pu&\link1&\fillleft\vrule & \cr}}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

But there is a problem with an alignment: number is between an arrow and an example… There is no such a problem with Steven B. Segletes’s solution. First I've tried to do it with  `tikz-dependency`, but there is the same alignment problem.