# underarrows with linguex examples

Tags: arrows, linguex

I'm working with linguex package. How can I draw underarrows to represent movement? I'm interesting in producing something like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the `gb4e` solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140142/movement-arrow-in-gloss) to your situation -- since that solution is based on `tikz`, it should apply to `linguex` in roughly the same way it would for `gb4e`.

Might be worth looking into the `tikz-qtree` package as well, it simplifies the `tikz`-interface for some common tasks that linguists need to achieve (e.g. movement arrows in trees, etc). Not sure if that package has anything built-in for glossed examples, but wouldn't be surprised if it did.

I tend to doubt that there is a `tikz`-free solution, unfortunately :/

Hope this helps ~~

Comment: Thanks. It does help (though I wish there was a simpler solution).

Comment: totally agreed -- i think that there is a pretty big demand among linguists for a streamlined graphics package for drawing types of diagrams that are common in linguistics but not elsewhere. your case is a good example of a common task that really shouldn't be that hard but still seems to be! best of luck ~~

Comment: The solution in the linked question has now been released as the [`movement-arrows`](https://ctan.org/pkg/movement-arrows) package.